# Oracle SQL Find Min and Max in a row with a tabl having n columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a SQL in oracle DB to find min and max values in row among col1...coln (where n could be anything between 1 to max columns allowed in oracle table)

```
data:

col1 col2 ... coln
---- ----      ----
  9    6        1
  5    3        2
  2    6        7

Expected o/p:

min_val   max_val
-------   -------
1          9
2          5
2          7
```

I will be grateful to receive any leads towards this question.

Thanks.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that.

Comment: Sounds like you have a really bad data model

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all col1, col2, ... colN are of type INT, one option is to use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions. But drawback is that you need to write all the columns in the parameters list of both the functions.

```
select LEAST(col1,col2,col3, ... ,coln) min_val,
 GREATEST(col1,col2,col3, ... ,coln) max_val
from table_name;
```

**Note:** You have to write all columns-names. Just for ease I have used ... Hope that is clear.

Below is what I have tested.

```
mysql> create table my_tab(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into my_tab values (9,6,1), (5,3,2), (2,6,7);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from my_tab;
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    9 |    6 |    1 |
|    5 |    3 |    2 |
|    2 |    6 |    7 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select LEAST(col1,col2,col3) min_val, GREATEST(col1,col2,col3) max_val from my_tab;
+---------+---------+
| min_val | max_val |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       9 |
|       2 |       5 |
|       2 |       7 |
+---------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't return in ascending and descending order as requested in question

Comment: @user7294900: You can check my test case. I am not sure what you have tried. There is nothing to do with order. Order is by default, i.e., insertion order of the rows.